# Replace a number with a word

Tags: python

Given a string. Replace in this string all the numbers 1 by the word one.

Example input:

```
1+1=2
```

wished output:

```
one+one=2
```

I tried the following but does not work with an int:

```
s=input()
print(s.replace(1,"one"))
```

How can I replace an integer?

Comment: SO isn't a replacement for basic tutorials. Read the error message, think about what it's telling you.

Comment: ... and post any errors you get or search for them here, for [example search for the error-message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+TypeError%3A%20replace()%20argument%201%20must%20be%20str%2C%20not%20int) like suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You got a `TypeError` like below.
Use `'1'` of type `str` as first argument (string instead number) because you want to work with strings and replace parts of the string `s`.

Try in Python console like:

```py
>>> s = '1+1=2'
>>> print(s.replace(1,"one"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: replace() argument 1 must be str, not int
>>> print(s.replace('1',"one"))
one+one=2
```

or simply use the string-conversion method [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str):

```
s.replace(str(1), 'one')
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you could simply use a replace(), I would suggest instead using a python dictionary. Defining each number to a word, that would then switch. Like this.

```
     conversion = {
         1: 'one',
         2: 'two'
     }
```

You can then use this like a dictionary

```
      print(conversion[1]) # "one"
      print(conversion[2]) # "two"
```

This simply makes your code more adaptable, in case you want to convert some numbers and not all. Just an alternative option to consider.